# opening a tab bar controller on successful login swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am extremely new to swift and storyboards. I have an initial view set which presents the user with login or register options. on the success of my login web service, I am trying to open a tab bar. I am getting into the success of the webservice as I can see the response.

My code for attempting to load the tab bar is as folllows in my initial view controller:

```
func loadHomeScreen()
    {
        emailField.text = ""
        passwordField.text = ""
        self.presentViewController(UIStoryboard.tabbarController()!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And at the very bottom of that file, I have the following:

```
private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

    class func tabbarController() -> TabbarController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarControllerID") as? TabbarController
    }
}
```

And in my storyboard I have given the tabbarcontroller the id above. When I run the app (tested on the simulator for iphone6), I am getting the error `'found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'` and this is pointing to the line of code in my loadHome func above (self.presentViewController(UIStoryboard.tabbarController()!, animated: true, completion: nil))

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: refer the answer below -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517047/tab-bar-after-login-why-does-it-look-like-this/36517380#36517380

Answer (score 0):

You could instead instantiate your storyboard like so and the code would look like this under `loadHomeScreen()`:

```
emailField.text = ""
passwordField.text = ""
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarControllerID") as! TabbarController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You may need to change the bundle to the "mainBundle" as you have in your code, but this should work.

This may not be the optimal solution if your plan is to extend `UIStoryboard` for instantiating your `ViewControllers` but I think this might be a little easier/cleaner, depending on how your project is set up.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, I had to change the private extension storyboard to as follows: private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }
    
    class func tabbarController() -> UITabBarController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarControllerID") as? UITabBarController
    }
}

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were subclassing UITabBarController to your own TabbarController class.